# Word 2007/10 hide figure label in table of figures

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2010

I have a load of figures in a document with standard captions ("figure n: some caption") and would like a table of figures.
However, in the table (not the captions) I don't want the label "Figure" to show at the start of every line, e.g. currently the table shows like so

```
figure 1....some caption
figure 2....another caption
```

and so on. I would like as follows

```
1....some caption
2....another caption
```

But I have not been able to determine if this is even possible in Word. To clarify the actual captions below each image still need to read "figure n: some caption", only in the table should the label not be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expected to be able to achieve this with Caption label (none) in Table of Figures but (strangely?) if selected the <kbd>OK</kbd> button is greyed out. However, if you select the Table and replace "figure " with nothing I think you should achieve what you are after.